# Surface Pro 3 or 4 - "network cable unplugged"

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, microsoft-surface

<sub>NOTE: Answering my own question to help community.</sub>

After a Windows Update I cannot access any WiFi on my Surface Pro.

In the Taskbar Network Settings it only shows Flight Mode, not the list of available WiFi devices.

Troubleshooting the issue I see symptoms such as:

- The Taskbar icon has a "Not connected to internet" with a red X.
- Using a `netsh interface show interface` the vEthernet for Marvell
  Wireless card is Enabled but its state is disconnected
- In Device Manager under Network Adapters, the Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC is ok: **This device is working properly.**
- When I browse to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Centre` and drill down I eventually see “network cable unplugged” for the vEthernet wireless nic.

How do I connect to WiFi again?

Answer (score 1):

Open a Command Prompt with Admin privileges (on Windows 10, right click Start button and choose "Command Prompt (Admin)") and execute this command:

```
netcfg -d
```

That net config command will output info like this:

> SetupDiCallClassInstaller Error: 0x6
>   ...
>   Successfully commited changes to the registry.
>   We are going to reboot now to complete the clean up. Save all of your work.

Restart the computer and if the Taskbar Network settings has a Yellow Exclamation Mark, right click and Choose Repair and that repair/troubleshoot utility in Windows *will actually* fix it!